# Allow @ special character but not as first character

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing UserId validation. I have added regex validation to allow numbers and characters in user id.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only characters and digits are allowed")]
```

How can I allow the "@" symbol in Userid but not as the first character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should see you through:

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9@]*$"
```

Comment: Op wants to allow `@` symbol.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Correct. And?

Comment: Your regex would match `Adfdgfgaf` string.

Comment: Yeah. "Allow" and "force" are different things.

Comment: Why not use `\w` simply?

Comment: @hjpotter92 because `\w` contains `_`